# What is the difference between 'exec ssh localhost' and 'ssh localhost'?

Tags: bash, ssh

I read `man exec` output, but did not understand the difference between these two commands: `exec ssh localhost` and `ssh localhost`.
I tested both commands and did not found any difference. Is there any differences?

Comment: `man exec` documents a c std library function, not the shell command `exec`. The shell command is probably implemented with one of the exec functions though.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296852/298504

Answer (score 2):

Those two are not same.

`exec` is a shell builtin which will execute the given command `ssh localhost` in this case with replacing the current shell with the command.

While doing simple `ssh localhost` you are executing general `ssh` command, there are no bells and whistles associated.

The effect will be apparent when you will `logout` of the `ssh` session :

- In the case of `exec ssh localhost` the shell will be replaced by `ssh lcoalhost`, after successful `ssh` you will get a shell as usual. While logging out of the `ssh` shell session e.g. by `logout` or `exit` you will not be back to the parent shell i.e. from the shell you have done `exec ssh localhost` as that has been replaced already. So you will simply lose this terminal tab/window.
- On the other hand for `ssh localhost`, as you are not replacing the parent shell with `ssh localhost` so after logging out you will be back to the parent shell i.e. the caller shell.

Comment: Hi Heemayl , I have tried what you have given but its behaving same in my case. Two commands are exhibiting same behaviour. Tried in SUSE(office)

Comment: @Raja Which shell ? which terminal ? how are you logging out ?

Comment: Shell : Bash , Taken access via SSH ,logging out via exit...

Comment: @Raja Is it a GNU `bash` ? i mean check what `help exec` say..

Comment: But I found this which says similar to you http://www.bottomupcs.com/fork_and_exec.html , I need to read more links to understand it better because it is something happens between kernel and OS.

Comment: @Raja That is how a new process is created, actually not the same `exec` here , that is the `exec()` system call..but the concept is somewhat similar..